# image magick couldn't load font error windows

Tags: windows-10, imagemagick, cairo, pango

I can't seem to use almost any of my system fonts without getting a:

couldn't load font error

on my windows 10. I have IM installed with cairo/pango and am trying to use convert.

I've found that Arial and Verdana work, but obscure fonts do not.

I have a type.xml that includes the type-windows.xml but adding

```
-font Comic-Sans-MS-Bold
```

still results in error.

I've used the various font listing commands like

```
identify -list font
convert -list font
```

and the output has many many fonts.